# vb.net retrieving data between 2 datepicker ... index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: .net, vb.net

Where did I go wrong? How can I pull out data between 2 dates

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try
         conn.Open()
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where check_date between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "# and #" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "#", conn)
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read
             DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("check_corporate"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("check_group"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("status"))
         End While
         dr.Dispose()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     End Try
     conn.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Add Using statements, use parameters for queries, don't concatenate strings for queries, and then step through with the debugger to see on which line you're getting the error.

Comment: Maybe you should have read about valid syntax for MySQL. Just writing SQL code without confirming that it's valid for your database was bound to end in tears.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Incorporating Andrew Mortimer's comments, which are correct for good programming practice.

I think you're getting the error because you're using VB formatting for a date instead of SQL formatting. Try replacing your line with this:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where check_date between @FirstDate and @SecondDate", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecondDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("check_corporate"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("check_group"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("status"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

SQL wants the single quote as a string/date delimiter, but if you use parameters you shouldn't need anything at all.

If this doesn't work, you need to provide which statement is actually causing the error. This would be in the stack trace, which is why I also changed the `MsgBox` to display `ex` as a whole. If your error is on the line for adding to the datagrid, you may have a typo in either the SQL column name, or the `Item` you specified.

Otherwise, we need more information to be able to narrow it down.

Comment: Tried your code, but doesn't seem to do anything. Nothing happens nor error popping up

Comment: @NnekLecxe, I modified my answer, which kind of changes it.

Comment: It says "System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.' 

Sorry, im not very well versed with mysql queries, parameters and such...

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? I will need to know the line number on which the error occurs, too, but I have no line numbers, so you will have to translate it to which line.

Comment: Try this Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where check_date between ( @FirstDate and @SecondDate"), conn) AND perhaps change "and" to a comma